# Immutable.js in Typescript with strictNullChecks

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, immutable.js

Likely a newbie question.

I'm trying to use `immutable.js` with Typescript with the compile flag `strictNullChecks` on.

I have this very simple scenario:

```ts
const concepts: List<String> = List.of('test');
concepts.map( concept => concept.length );
```

On the second line I get `Object is possibly undefined`, and I'm informed that `concept` is of type `String | undefined`. But why?

I even tried

```
List.of('test', undefined);
```

and I get a error, so... why?!

Comment: Could you try this with `(concept: string) => `?
TS is evidently wrong here, so if it still fails on a nightly this would merit filing a bug report with TS. You may wanna search for this error over there too in case others already did.